# Why lieing is allowed for saving ourself?

Tags: mahabharata

In Hindu scritures we are allowed to tell lie in some cases.

> In a situation of peril to life and in marriage, falsehood becomes utterable. In a situation involving the loss of one’s entire property, falsehood becomes utterable. **On an occasion of marriage, or of enjoying a woman, or when life is in danger**, or when one’s entire property is about to be taken away, or for the sake of a Brahmana, falsehood may be uttered. These five kinds of falsehood have been declared to be sinless. On these occasions falsehood would become truth and truth would become falsehood.”
>
> [Karna parva](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://en.krishnakosh.org/krishna/Mahabharata_Karna_parva_Chapter_69:2&ved=2ahUKEwjdnpuBwKvpAhVTaCsKHQHCCqMQFjACegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2mFLgbHkjHQEHFafQMqSRM&cshid=1589189497283)

So what if we lied to save ourselves from the punishment of crime that we done?

Comment: Also, to seduce women you may lie apparently.

Comment: The next line is: "These five kinds of falsehood have been declared to be sinless. " so if you save your life by committing a crime then that is not a sin. It is the same for Kshatriyaa they are allowd to kill the bad without any sin occurred.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The quotation you gave does not say "...or to save yourself from the death penalty by committing a crime."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exception to lying doesn't apply to criminals who want to escape from punishment.

> 5. (Witnesses) shall not speak singly or without being asked,
> 6. And if, (being asked,) they do not answer, they are guilty of a crime.
> 7. Heaven is their reward, if they speak the truth; in the contrary case hell (will be their portion).
>
> ...
>
> 11. If the sacred law or the rules (referring to worldly matters) are violated, the guilt (falls) on the witnesses, the assessors, the king, and on the offender.
>
> ...
>
> 23. A witness must be reprimanded and punished for speaking an untruth.
> 24. No guilt is incurred by giving false evidence, in case the life (of a man) depends thereon.
> 25. But (this rule **does**) **not** (**hold good**) **if the life of a very wicked** (**man** **depends on the evidence of a witness**).
>
> ([Gautama Dharmasūtra, Chapter XIII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/gautama-dharmas%C5%ABtra/d/doc116313.html))